# gtk app cant see windows path value to use gtk+ dlls

Tags: windows, ubuntu, path, gtk

I added `c:\_hub\gtk\bin` to windows path var, and still when I try to run gtk app, it shows me an error about missing dll. if I will put my app to `c:\_hub\gtk\bin`, it will run.

any ideas?

> I use codeblocks. created project in this way: file > new > gtk+ app
>   Wizard asked me to show gtk dir, I pointed him to gtk dir. then wrote
>   a simple -> build.
>
> as you can see, I didnt add any compiler params etc

Comment: I don't have an answer (I use Linux, not MSWindows) but want to say you should (a) show exact copies of the commands you used to run or try to run the app, (b) show exact copy of the error, (c) tell where the app bin is located, and (d) tell where the dll is located that apparently is found when you run the program one way but not another.   In other words, it looks to me like your question is not clear or complete enough to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that was using Total commander and when I changed enviroment variables in windows, it wont change in Total commander session. So I had to close total commander, change enviroment and then everything was ok.